# how to override calculateRenderKitId API

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am making a webpage and Now i want to make a mobile version of this webpage. My question is how can i use the same Application to work for both desktop and mobile browser( I am using Fennec verson of mozilla). 
how can my application detect whether it is accesed through which browser(desktop or mobile).
I am using jsf 2.0 and primefaces 2.2 i have read somewhere that by overriding calculateRenderKitId API we can do it. Has any body done that.
(I have separate pages for mobile version and desktop but the backing beans are same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can my application detect whether it is accesed through which browser(desktop or mobile)

You can check the request headers to detect which is the client

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

and here is the [list of user agent](http://user-agent-string.info/)

Comment: can you explain that in little more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override JSF view handler, so just write a class that extends ViewHandlerWrapper and override calculateRenderKitId there.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.html

After that configure your view handler in faces-config.xml.

Comment: I don't understand what to return in getWrapped() when overriding ViewHandlerWrapper.
Can anybody explain this to me?